# Magento 2: How to add multiple AND conditions to one single attribute that could be used to join other condition groups?

Tags: magento2, product-collection, eav-attributes

I could filter a product collection by **(attribute A: condition A OR condition B) AND (attribute B: condition C OR condition D)** with the following codes:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute A', [
  [condition here...], //e.g. ['neq' => 'x']
  [condition here...] //e.g. ['gt' => 'y']
]);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute B', [
  [condition here...],
  [condition here...]
]);
```

But I have no idea how to achieve this:
**(attribute A: condition A AND condition B) OR (attribute B: condition C and condition D)**

I have also tried to use search criteria builder, but still no luck so far.

Comment: Try like:  

    `$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute A', [
      [condition here... , condition here...],
    ]);`

Comment: @magefms The conditions A and B I want would be something like ['gt' => 'xxx'] and ['neq' => 'yyy']. The syntax you provided seems not working.

Comment: why not try like   `$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute A', [
    [condition here...]
]);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute A', [
    [condition here number 2...]
]);`

Comment: creating two filter for the same attribute that might work

Comment: can you try like `$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array(array('attribute' => 'attribute A', 'neq' => 'x'), array('attribute' => 'attribute A', 'gt' => 'y')),
        array(array('attribute' => 'attribute B', 'neq' => 'x'), array('attribute' => 'attribute B', 'neq' => 'x'))
    )
);`

Comment: I got this error: `Undefined index: attribute in /foo/bar/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php`